# Use CSS to make table-esque box of short columns from a single div of links

Tags: css, list, css-tables

I have this plugin that displays a tag cloud for Wordpress (http://www.hothouseblog.org/). Typically it displays in a horizontal running list. I seek the answer to turn this list into three or four columns of vertically-running items.

With CSS, I've gotten the items to display in rows, but still the links are running horizontally, while I want the items to be vertically stacked. Is this a pipe dream?

```
.widget_tag_cloud {
display: table;
background-color: #000000;
padding: 10px 20px;
width: 580px;
height: 200px!important;}

.widget_tag_cloud a {
font-size: 14px!important;
text-transform: uppercase;
float: left;
width: 100px;
display: block;}
```

Comment: Please add the markup (HTML), as your current structure isn't completely clear (could be `.widget_tag_cloud > * ... * > a`).

Answer (score 0):

In its current html format, yes, that would be a pipe dream. Anchor elements aren't design for that. You have to section them into `div` columns or split them into stacks of `ul >li` lists instead. And `display: table;` isn't really appropriate here.

Filling a box the way you are trying to do it, with a vertical constrain, is almost impossible unless perhaps using multiple `:nth-child()` pseudo-classes, but that would be a convoluted solution which would require a javacript polyfill for IE8 to support it.

Comment: Ah ha; I see. Okay, so I imagine that there is some way of changing the php to affect the output of the plugin to have them separate into div columns or stacks of ul >li lists, but that's really beyond my skill set. I do appreciate the feedback!